# I am using r to calculate d prime. It z transforms my proportions. Why do we need the z transformed values?

Tags: r, statistics, probability-theory

I am not sure why the program z transforms my hit rate and false alarm rates while calculating d prime. Why should they be z transformed before subtracting? Thanks in advance :)

I thought it would give a difference but it ztransforms before giving the difference

Comment: I think this belongs on stats.stackexchange.com
"Q&A for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization"

Comment: I also think this should be on CrossValidated, but as I am relatively familiar with d', I am giving you some comment. In fact, d' is calculated by this formula: $Z_{hit}-Z_{FA}$, and $Z$ here just means the z transforming.